# Time Complexity of Nested For Loop with If

Tags: c++, loops, runtime, time-complexity, big-o

```
void f(int n)
{
  for(int i =1; i<=n; i++){
    if(i % (int)sqrt(n)==0){
      for(int k=0; k< pow(i,3); k++){
        //do something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My thinking process:
number of times execute if statement: sum i=1 to n (theta(1)).

number of times execute things inside if: sum i=1 to sqrt(n) (for loop)

number of times execute for loops: sum k=0 to i^3 (theta(1)) = i^3

This will give me: theta(n) + sum i=0 to sqrt(n) (theta(i^3)) = theta(n) + theta(n^2)

which gives me theta(n^2)

The answer key he gave is theta(n^3.5)

I am just wondering if i made any mistake on my thinking process. I have asked my professor twice about this question. Just want to see if there is anything I didn't see before I bother him again.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Sigma notation, I came up with the exact closed-form.

Besides, the formula below assumes the process, which doesn't verify the condition that executes the innermost loop, is negligible.

[image]

It's up to you to determine tight order of growth bounds, because of flooring function and square root etc.

Further details here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840414/summation-with-floor-and-square-root-functions-tight-bounds

Answer (score 0):

```
void f(int n) {   
  for(int i =1; i<=n; i++){     //---   n times
    if(i % (int)sqrt(n)==0){    // ---  2 times (constant)
      for(int k=0; k< pow(i,3); k++){  // sqrt(n)^3 and n^3 times
        //do something
      }
    }   
  } 
}
```

> Taking the highest order term it should be Theta(n^3)
>
> Assuming do something is constant
>
> c = do somrthing + plus running cost of single iteration of inner
>   loop
>
> a = runnning cost of running single iteration of outer most loop
>
> b = running cost of if block Thinking more about it  c*n^3/2 + c*n^3
>   + a*n + b*2)
>
> Taking the highest order term Theta(n^3) or
>   since  c is same coefficient for both  the n^3 and n^3/2 we can reduce
>   it
>
> = cn^3 + cn^3/2
>
> = cn^3(n^1/2+1)
>
> ~ cn^3 * n^1/2
>
> = cn^3.5