# How to verify time complexity of algorithm from execution time?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If a run an algorithm I have calculated to be `O(n^2)` on two different n's, all else constant, can I verify it is `O(n^2)` by comparing execution times? For example, `n1 = 50` and `n2 = 100`. Since `n2` is `n1`, `time2` should be `(n2 - n1)^2` times larger than `time1`, right? Or is verification only possible with a graph?

Comment: time2 is larger than time1 by `(n2/n1)^2`, not `(n2-n1)^2`

Comment: It's probably better to use more than two values of n; e.g. if the execution time goes from 2 to 4, that could be 2+2, or 2*2, or 2^2. A third point will give you more information.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up plotting runtime vs. n for what I needed the verification for, but did notice it was (n2/n1)^2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982893/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop-with-if/38025211#38025211

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on meaning of "verify".

If you mean formally verify (i.e. prove) then:

No, but both plotting or just comparing the number can give you confidence that it is O(n^2) - and it is normally easier to prove that something is true if you are already confident what the result should be, and that it is true.

The reasons you cannot prove it that way are e.g.:

- The algorithm may be slow for some inputs, and you are not triggering that. Note that "random" inputs are not ideal for such testing.
- The complexity could be 100*n+n*log(n) - you are likely to see this as O(n) if you plot it for "small" values of n.
- The complexity is normally stated for an ideal computer, whereas you run on an actual computer. Thus when timing you will see a slow-down due to running out of memory caches which shouldn't be part of the ideal complexity.

If you use "verify" to mean "experimentally test" that e.g. an O(n^2) algorithm is in fact O(n^2), then, yes you can do that with both methods.

Comment: Thanks, I mean "verify" to mean experimentally test. I had already formally proven the complexity, but was required to show quantitative "proof", as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I verify it is O(n^2) by comparing execution times?

No.

`Time complexity` is pure theoretical concept. You cannot directly establish relation between execution times and time complexity .

To verify if an algorithm is O(n^2), you should be dependent only on the algorithm itself.

Comment: That's kind of debatable. The whole idea of **time** complexity is that the algorithm takes more **time** to execute. It's a bit pointless to use one run with one set of data, but if you run it multiple times with different data, you'll clearly see the difference when plotting a graph of the times.

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't be relied upon, but I am required to do so for a project

Comment: If you wish to compare two different algorithms you can compare their time complexity classes. But to verify if the algorithm is O(n^2) you must not rely on execution times. To put it other way, if you want to ask someone the time complexity of an algo, just explain them the algo. You need not write code, run it multiple times to plot execution times vs input size. Plotting the graph might give you some idea, but that cannot be accepted as a verification of time complexity of an algo.